# Wso2 bulk PDP query

Tags: optimization, wso2, xacml, pdp

Is there some option in wso2 PDP for making a single request for a sum of resources?

I think that having something like that can really improve the performance instead of asking the PDP every time. It would be great if I could make a single request and get all the access rights for a single user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found that there is an endpoint `/entitled-attribs`. You can find it in the [docs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Entitlement+with+APIs) .

So the description says `Get entitled attributes for a given set of parameters.`

You can post other parameters as well but by posting something like :

```
{
    "subjectName":"somename"
}
```

you can get a response of the resources and the actions that the user can do :

```
{
"entitledResultSetDTO": {
    "entitledAttributesDTOs": [
        {
            "resourceName": "SomeResource_Name",
            "action": "some_action_on_the_resource",
            "environment": null,
            "allActions": false,
            "allResources": false,
            "attributeDTOs": []
        },
        {
            "resourceName": "SomeOtherResource_Name",
            "action": "some_other_action_on_the_resource",
            "environment": null,
            "allActions": false,
            "allResources": false,
            "attributeDTOs": []
        }
    ],
    "advanceResult": false,
    "message": null,
    "messageType": null
}
```

And from here on we can just parse this response depending on our needs.